# How do you use the Angular package in NodeJS and Express?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I installed the Angular package via npm install for my Express project, but I have no idea how to use it.

How is it used if installed in this manner?

Or is the only way to use Angular is to include it using "script" in the html page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client-side modules that are published to npm are meant to be compiled with something like [browserify](http://browserify.org/). All browserify does is look through all the `require` statements in the code, pulls in the module using CommonJS (node) conventions, and concatenates all the files together into one minified JS file that you can then reference on your web page.

You can see the [npm package for Angular](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular) even says in its description that you should use something like browserify:

> AngularJS provided as a CommonJS module. Compiled with jsdom when running in Node. Useful for client-side apps built with Browserify and for testing AngularJS code in Node without depending on a browser.

People like to use browserify because you can use `require` to require other scripts. Instead of throwing ten script tags on the page you just build your client-side app like a node app and then you use browserify to tie it all together into a single script you can drop on your page.

If you've heard of [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), those are build tools that help automate all sorts of tasks at build time. Browserifying your client-side app(s) is one of the common tasks performed by those libraries.

Just don't confuse yourself by thinking your server-side node code can somehow talk to the angular code. Looks like the most you'll be able to do server-side is testing in node instead of in the browser with something like [Karma](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma).

---

Personally I prefer to use CDNs for libraries like AngularJS, but that's purely personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to use [bower](http://bower.io/) for the client side stuff (including angular). Use npm for server side and tooling (build system, testing).

A good project to see how the pieces fit together is [angular fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) (install [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) first).